# Video Synchronizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I want to build a video editing studio for a project. my project based on e-learning system. in this project I record 3 videos like (lecturer view, presentation view and whiteboard view)

then I want to sync those 3 videos and get **one output video.**

This is the scratch of this 
[image: sample scratch]

**important notice:**
those 3 videos should be can resize to change sizes, dragging to change place and deleting.
you can use javascript, jquery, html, css or React Js to done this

please help me...........

I tried for one video. sample code in follow

[image]

Thank you very much